# Creating lorem ipsum translations for Rails I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have a big Rails app that I've I18ned. It hasn't yet been translated to any language, but I extracted 99% of the strings into yaml. They come from all over the place - views, models, JS.

There's that remaining 1%, and tracking it down is proving tricky.

I would like to take my existing yaml files and "translate" them into a new language, Lorem Ipsum. I.e, to run the files through some processor that would produce valid i18n locale YAML, with gibberish content.

I would then import these, switch to the test locale (I could call these es.yml, or whatever) and cruise through my app looking for broken formatting and English-language strings.

The only slight problem is... how do I produce this lorem ipsum file? I can't just lorem all of the quoted strings, because there are I18n tokens of several format there.

Any ideas/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: How about just override the `I18n` methods to produce the gibberish?

Comment: Interesting idea, thank you! But then how would the generated lorem ipsum correspond in length to the yaml values?

Comment: Your method could interpret the length of the actual result and return a lorem ipsum string of the same length. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I'm overriding `I18n#translate` to return lorem ipsum of the expected text length. I haven't tested this, but in theory, it would look something like this:

```
module I18n

  alias_method :translate_without_lorem_ipsum, :translate

  def translate_with_lorem_ipsum(*args)
    actual_text = translate_without_lorem_ipsum(*args)
    LoremIpsum.text_with_length(actual_text.length) # imaginary method returning text of given length
  end

  alias_method :translate, :translate_with_lorem_ipsum

end
```

Since you're using rails, you could replace the `alias_method` usage with `alias_method_chain`.